# JAVASCRIPT: Convert text to string/int

Tags: javascript, jquery

is it possible to convert a text from an input to a string or integer?

I have an input field, in which you can search a company:

```
<input type="text" id="company" name="company" />
```

Now I need the value as a string or int.

Thanks for you help.

Comment: Did you try googling the answer? Here are some keywords you can try "javascript input text value".

Comment: Use **parseInt()** function for converting value in integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Value of the input field is a **string** by default. You can convert it to an **int** by

```
parseInt(document.getElementById("company").value,10);
```

Comment: I'd suggest to use `parseInt` with base argument.

Comment: don't forget to add the base argument `parseInt(value, 10)`

Comment: +1 few seconds faster than me.

Comment: By default, the base is 10, so you can ignore it.

Comment: @JitendraPancholi In case if the string value starts with `0`, the base will be considered as `8`.

Comment: Older browsers will result `parseInt("010")` as 8

Comment: @VisioN, spas: Thanks for the info. +1 for the same :)

Comment: just wanted to give an example :) its true that modern browsers will default to base 10

Comment: @All, Edited the answer with base argument. :-)

Comment: @Dilantha: thanks, but all I get is a NaN. For example my input field has the value Apple but when I do this:

var test = parseInt(document.getElementById("company").value);
console.log(test);

I get a NaN in the console.

Comment: @kathi Thants because "Apple" cannot be converted to an integer :-)

Comment: okay. I thought there is a way to convert a word to an integer.
thanks again for your help. I really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

jquery version:

`parseInt($( "#company" ).val(), 10);`

plain javascript:

`parseIntdocument.getElementById('company').value, 10);`

Comment: What is this? Where did you converted into integer?

Answer (score 0):

It is Simple stuff. You can convert by using parseInt() Function.

It will convert your string to Integer.

```
function convert()
 {
     var x=document.getElemenyById("company").value;
     x=parseInt(x);
 }
```

Comment: Already answered by @Dilantha